# Control the endpoint using Kaa

Tags: iot, endpoint, kaa

I am trying to build a simple scenario so that I can control an endpoint "on/off" using Kaa, but I need to know how can I auth the endpoint ? I mean how can I manage that some specific end point that is being controlled ?
Also is there any way so that I can identify a point and then allow/deny the connection from the EP to Kaa ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For details of endpoint authentication please refer to the [Endpoint provisioning and registration](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/)
documentation. You can use internal [credentials service](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/#credentials-service) 
to allows connection to Kaa cluster only to specified list of endpoints whose credentials were previously provisioned to Kaa server.

To control your endpoint by your server-side applications read about [Server-side EP profile](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Endpoint-profiles/#server-side-ep-profile) and [Endpoint-groups](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Endpoint-groups/) features.