# What is "Endpoints profiles" in admin UI mean?

Tags: kaa

I have two endpoints belong one user in my application, but I only look one endpoint in "Endpoints profiles" in admin UI. why ? I think in sdk maybe have api to set client id to identify, but I can not find it.

In tab "Endpoints profiles" in admin UI, I look at "Endpoint KeyHash is rV1sNE5XYqBFIDVSYbNATyZD2ts=", does the KeyHash is unique identification ? if yes, how can I change it?

In my opinion, In admin UI I produce one sdk, the sdk should be used in many endpoints, everyone endpoint have one id. Thanks to everyone which reply to me.

I see "Your first Kaa application" in doc, and followed it.
I test in 0.09.0 version, I found kaa 0.10.0 version release, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I speak English a little bit, but I try to answer:

In one time ONLY 1 EP for CLIENT and 1 EP for server-side can be active

The EP activated by RULES in ENDPOINT GROUP, that U seted for each of EG

check the rules for ENDPOINT GROUP started from MIN to MAX index

[Control the endpoint using Kaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306710/control-the-endpoint-using-kaa)

Comment: Thank you very much,  My english is also poor, where you come from ?  chinese ok?
I think one EP default belong one EG. So it is not problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Administration UI Endpoint profiles section you should see all previously connected endpoints. Endpoint Key hash is a unique identifier of endpoint generated during the endpoint registration process. So everyone endpoints have not one identifier.
Provide detailed steps to reproduce your issue and add Kaa server and clients logs with TRACE log level, for details refer to [Troubleshooting](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/Troubleshooting/) guide. 
Also reffer to [Endpoint profiles](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Endpoint-profiles/) and [Endpoint provisioning and registration](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/) 
guides for details.

Comment: I want to log my opration, but I encounter “REFUSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS“ Error, operation server can not connect. So, sorry , I have not fixed this problem. .........................
<pre>
log :
[pool-6-thread-1] INFO  o.k.k.c.c.i.c.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - ConnAck (REFUSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS) message received for channel [default_operation_tcp_channel]
[pool-6-thread-1] ERROR o.k.k.c.c.i.c.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Connection for channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] was rejected: REFUSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS</pre>

Comment: You received REFUSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS in the case of invalid authentication parameters were provided. Provision endpoint credentials to Kaa server before endpoint connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you . How I can fixed it?  I look two file (key.private and key.public) in my java source folder, I copy it to Kaa server? Where it is in my server?

Comment: Try our Credentials demos in [Kaa 0.10.0 Sandbox](http://www.kaaproject.org/download-kaa/) for a detailed explanation of Credentials management feature. This application bundle uses the Credentials management extension for the full-cycle management of credentials in the Kaa platform.

Comment: Can I close this Credentials ? I just test kaa.  Kaa is great.

Comment: What did you mean by saying: "Can I close this Credentials ?".